Taking on someones sin
There is an authentic hadith in bukhari about the punishment of backbiting. People you have wronged take your good deeds or you take their bad ones. But in the Holy Quran Allah(s.w.t) says that "None can take the burdens of others". My question is how do we reconcile this hadith and the Quran, and is the sin of backbiting an exception of the rizling in the Quran? Jazakallah

Looks like one part is only in the Sunnah, not reviled in the Quran itself: https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6534

From the pure logic and semantics of the statements, it is different if on takes the another ones bad deeds out of free will, or ALLAH Himself transfers good deeds from the wrongdoer to his victim and bad deeds the other way. Hoping for an answer based on Islam.
